# Batch - The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter substitution is invalid - Archiving Google Chrome Downloads Folder

Tags: batch-file

A made a batch file to archive monthly (using the task scheduler from windows) the Google Chrome Downloads folder (on my windows 7 64-bit pc).
It should move files from sertain filetypes to another folder, if it hasn't been modified last month. The folder where the file should move to is depending on the last modified date.

So i made the folowing batchfile:

```
@ECHO OFF
CD C:\Users\Dagan\Downloads
FORFILES /m (DIR (FOR %%G IN (*.doc *.pdf) do echo %%G) /A /O:D /T:C /B /D) /c "FOR %Q IN (@path) DO ((SET year=%%~tG ) && (SET year=%year~6,4%) && (SET month=%%~tG) && (SET month=%month~3,2%) && (MOVE %%G "C:\Users\Dagan\DownloadArchives\"%year%"\"%month%"\") && (SET year=) && (SET month=))" /d -31
CD C:\Users\Dagan\Desktop
```

But it isn't working and i get the following error:

```
The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter substitution is invalid: %~tG ) && (SET year=%year~6,4%) && (SET month=%
%~tG) && (SET month=%month~3,2%) && (MOVE %%G "C:\Users\Dagan\DownloadArchives\"%
year%"\"%month%"\") && (SET year=) && (SET month=))" /d -31


For valid formats type CALL /? or FOR /?
☺ is not expected at this point.
```

Can someone please help me with this?

PS: Here is my batchfile again, but now formatted for better reading:

```
@ECHO OFF
CD C:\Users\Dagan\Downloads
FORFILES /m (
  DIR (
    FOR %%G IN (
      *.doc *.pdf
    ) do echo %%G
  ) /A /O:D /T:C /B /D
) /c "
  FOR %Q IN (@path) DO (
    (SET year=%%~tG ) && (SET year=%year~6,4%) && (SET month=%%~tG) && (SET month=%month~3,2%) && 
    (MOVE %%G "C:\Users\Dagan\DownloadArchives\"%year%"\"%month%"\") && 
    (SET year=) && (SET month=)
  )
" /d -31
CD C:\Users\Dagan\Desktop
```

Comment: did the more readable batch file actually run? For me it gives `ERROR: Files of type "(" not found.`

Answer (score 0):

I think the '@' in your path variable is the issue. I don't think CMD expands the path in that Perl array syntax.